# Por que se invalida/destruye mi WebSession al cerrar un PopUp?

Tags: genexus

Al **cerrar/salir de un WebPanel** que fue llamado utilizando el metodo **PopUp** se **Invalida/Destruye la Sesion Web**.

`webpanel.popup()`

**Ocurre sin importar** que el popup llamado **tenga o no parametros y sin importar si el caller es otro WebPanel, Transaccion, WWPanel.**

**Probe cambiar algunas propiedades:**

- Cambie la propiedad **Encrypt URL Parameters** de los paneles de No a Session Key y viceversa. Sin resultados.
- Cambie la propiedad **Web User Experience** de Smooth a Previous Versions Comp. pero asi ni me llega a cargar el PopUp, solo oscurece la pantalla y el presionar ESC vuelve al caller y de vuelta con la sesion destruida.

Pasa con **todos los popups de paneles, no asi con popups de reportes.**

Si se llama a los **paneles sin utilizar el metodo PopUp no ocurre el problema** y se mantiene la WebSession.

Answer (score 1):

Por algun motivo que desconozco, al abrir cualquier panel como popup se ejecutaba por debajo otro panel (logout) que tenia entre sus eventos un &websession.destroy()

Como se puede ver en el access_log del tomcat:
[image: access_log del Tomcat]

Este webpanel que ejecutaba el destroy de la sesion, es un webpanel que no tiene ninguna Referencia en el proyecto.

Al intentar eliminar de la KB no permite dicha accion porque segun el mensaje este panel esta siendo Referenciado por otro panel (cosa que no es asi).

Como solucion temporal se comento todo el tab Events del panel logout (solo tenia el Start con el session.destroy).
Por alguna razon se sigue llamando al panel pero ya no tiene ningun evento que ejecutar. Y todo corre con normalidad.